# Logstash Input from Elasticsearch Error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm using Logstash 1.5.4 and Elasticsearch 1.7.1

The following is my Logstash configuration file:

```
input {
        elasticsearch {
                host => localhost
        }
}


output {
        elasticsearch {
                host => localhost
        }
        stdout {
                codec => rubydebug
        }
}
```

This works fine when I don't include the 'host' option for Elasticsearch input. However, once I add it, it gives me the following error and shuts Logstash off:

```
←[31mUnknown setting 'host' for elasticsearch {:level=>:error}←[0m
Error: Something is wrong with your configuration.
You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can
use to validate logstash's configuration before you choose
to restart a running system.
```

Now I *know* that using Host is optional, but I need it. What if later on I wanted an Elasticsearch input from a host other that localhost?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `elasticsearch` input, the correct parameter name to use is [`hosts`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-inputs-elasticsearch-hosts) not `host`.

```
input {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "localhost"
        }
}
...
```

So `host` is actually a documentation bug. The Ruby source for the [elasticsearch input plugin](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/elasticsearch.rb#L37) also tells the same story.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Why isn't this mentioned in the doc's very first example! https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html

Comment: Documentation bug, I guess ;)

Comment: To note, in output it should be "host" only, not "hosts" for Logstash 1.5. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/1.5/configuration.html

Comment: In the `elasticsearch` input, it's `hosts` no matter which version. However, in the `elasticsearch` output, it was `host` before Logstash 2.0 and then the property name has been standardized to `hosts`.

Comment: Excellent, this saved my life with `elasticsearch` 5.0.1. +1